# notifyDataSetChanged not working with Threads

Tags: java, android

I have a problem to update my UI by use of the notifyDataSetChanged method. 
If I do this without using thread it will work.

The following class implements the Runnable interface which gets data through Web API and it updates my db. 
After it updates the data I want to update my UI, but it wont work with the thread concept.

```
public class ExchangeRateUpdateRunnable implements Runnable {

private ExchangeRateDatabase db;
private CustomAdapter adapter;

public ExchangeRateUpdateRunnable(ExchangeRateDatabase db, CustomAdapter adapter) { this.db = db; this.adapter = adapter;}

@Override
public void run() {
    refresh();
}

private void refresh() {
    List<ExchangeRate> exchangeRates = new ArrayList<>();
    String urlString = "https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml";
    try {

        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        String encoding = connection.getContentEncoding();

        XmlPullParser parser = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance().newPullParser();
        parser.setInput(inputStream, encoding);

        int eventType = parser.getEventType();
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                if ("Cube".equals(parser.getName())) {
                    if(parser.getAttributeValue(null,"currency") != null) {
                        String currency = parser.getAttributeValue(null , "currency");
                        String rate = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "rate");
                        ExchangeRate exchangeRate = new ExchangeRate(currency, new Double(rate));
                        exchangeRates.add(exchangeRate);
                    }
                }
            }
            eventType = parser.next();
        }
        inputStream.close();
        updateDB(exchangeRates);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void updateDB ( List<ExchangeRate> exchangeRates) {
    db.setExchangeRate(exchangeRates);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

And this is a method that is implemented on the mainActivity class, which listens to menu items (This means as soon as I click on the item it will call this function). It implements the Thread that runs on the background and updates my data:

```
 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.settings:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, CurrencyListActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        case R.id.refresh:
            new Thread(new ExchangeRateUpdateRunnable(db,adapter)).start();
           //new RefreshRates(db,adapter).refresh(); //single Threaded
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

If I put the codeline: adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); on the method of the mainActivity class it will only work when I click the button twice. But I want to update my UI as soon as I click on the button.

How do I solve this problem ?
Is this a Thread problem or something that Android cant handle by use of Threads?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to notifytheDataSetChange from thread,  you might need to use the handler.post or runOnUiThread to achieve this.

Example

```
try {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Log.e("updating...", "");
                            Notifydatasetchanged()
                        }
                    });
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: it works, can u explain why this works. What happens exactly if i run an runOnuiThread. This is hard to imagine

Comment: is there are other option instead of just use the sleep ? I would like to update as soon as the updates are finish. not just randomly sleep and hope its done. what happens if it takes too long?

Comment: Ui cannot be touched from background thread,  android won't allow

Comment: Please accept the answer and do upvote,  it will help others as well. Thanks @kubilay Anil